# angular-ui-router url in address bar fails but state works with html5mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, address-bar

I have a component I want to call

```
$stateProvider
.state('authorized', { url: '/authorized', template: '<authorize></authorize>' })

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but when I do this in the address bar, there is a 404 not found, when I call it by its state there is no problem.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/authorized 404 (Not Found)
```

But when I would add this component to another state I already had, I can access it in the address bar.

```
.state('pallettypes', {
      url: '/pallettypes',
      template: '<authorize></authorize>'
  })
```

Can somebody please tell me why the former doesn't work and the latter doesn't give an error?

Comment: what ever you write in url is write, it should work, Clear the cache of browser or clean and buil project, may be it will work

Comment: I did what u told me, but that doesn't fix it

Comment: See whatever you share is write, may be there is some another issue so share some more code related to this. Like `$stateProvider`, `.config`..

Comment: Solved my problem with adding a Asp.Net MVC controller for it. I forgot to mention i'm using it with angular